# read file in descending php

Tags: php

hi im trying to read a file in descending order.
i want to echo last 10 words from the file 
expected result:

> brian tracy, brian tracy, der reiche
>   sack, der reiche sack, der reiche
>   sack, electrical machines by charles s
>   siskind second e, test de politica
>   fiscal, gigantomastia,gigantomastia,,
>   a,

file i want to read :

> find a doctor, Find a Doctor,technique with fingers of right hand over left ven, la empresa adaptable, la empresa adaptable en la era de la informaci n, la pobre mia, probabilidad estadistica, crack beam, dwarf rabbit, probabilidad estadistica, kamsutra bangla, power of the dog, power of the dog, prinsip kerja uji ninhidrin, letramania 3, gre, gre, prinsip kerja uji ninhidrin, prinsip kerja uji ninhidrin, artificial intelligence a modern approach, configuring sap erp financials and controlling, gas spring, imperio carolingio, blue collar man, caligrafia, wonderlic, women and weight loss tamasha, women and the weight loss tamasha, vivir amar y aprender leo buscaglia, vivir amar y aprender leo buscaglia, wonderlic, plan de manejo ambiental, calibra o de manometros, curso de carpinteria, secreto industrial, secreto industrial, deneme, elementos secundarios de un triangulo, imperio carolingio, caligrafia, construir en lo construido, plan de manejo ambiental, lisboa, lisboa secreta, modelo de contrato secreto industrial, el conde de montecristo, metode titrasi formol, metode titrasi formol, probabilidad estadistica, probabilidad estadistica, history of islam akbar shah najeebabadi, caligrafia, caligrafia, conversacion en la catedral, brian tracy, brian tracy, der reiche sack, der reiche sack, der reiche sack, electrical machines by charles s siskind second e, test de politica fiscal, gigantomastia,gigantomastia, Find a Doctor, Find a Doctor,technique with fingers of right hand over left ven, la empresa adaptable, la empresa adaptable en la era de la informaci n, la pobre mia, probabilidad estadistica, crack beam, dwarf rabbit, probabilidad estadistica, kamsutra bangla, power of the dog, power of the dog, prinsip kerja uji ninhidrin, letramania 3, gre, gre, prinsip kerja uji ninhidrin, prinsip kerja uji ninhidrin, artificial intelligence a modern approach, configuring sap erp financials and controlling, gas spring, imperio carolingio, blue collar man, caligrafia, wonderlic, women and weight loss tamasha, women and the weight loss tamasha, vivir amar y aprender leo buscaglia, vivir amar y aprender leo buscaglia, wonderlic, plan de manejo ambiental, calibra o de manometros, curso de carpinteria, secreto industrial, secreto industrial, deneme, elementos secundarios de un triangulo, imperio carolingio, caligrafia, construir en lo construido, plan de manejo ambiental, lisboa, lisboa secreta, modelo de contrato secreto industrial, el conde de montecristo, metode titrasi formol, metode titrasi formol, probabilidad estadistica, probabilidad estadistica, history of islam akbar shah najeebabadi, caligrafia, caligrafia, conversacion en la catedral, brian tracy, brian tracy, der reiche sack, der reiche sack, der reiche sack, electrical machines by charles s siskind second e, test de politica fiscal, gigantomastia,gigantomastia,, a,

Comment: That looks far too much like a typical link farm spam page for me to consider answering this.

Comment: where is the question? What is the expected result?

Comment: the "expected result" contains more than 10 words... can you clarify exactly what you're trying to do, why? Can you use a database instead? In other words, where is that file coming from? Is it created by an external source, etc.? What can be the maximum potential size of the file (how big can it become)? etc.

Comment: @Yanick I think he means last 10 values separated by commas

Answer (score 4):

If the file will not be too big, you can simply read it all and then remove the data you don't need :

```
$content = file_get_contents($filename);    // $filename is the file to read
$chunks = explode($delimiter, $content);    // $delimiter is your word separator

$chunks = array_slice($chunks, -$n);        // $n is the number of words to keep from the end of the file
                                            // NOTE : -$n !
```

If the file will grow beyond reasonable size to be loaded into memory, you may read it in chunks. Something like (untested) :

```
function getLastTokens($filename, $n, $delimiter) {
   $offset = filesize($filename);
   $chunksize = 4096;  // 4K chunk

   if ($offset <= $chunksize * 2) {
      // our one liner here because the file is samll enough
      $tokens = explode($delimiter, file_get_contents($filename)); 

   } else {
      $tokens = array();

      $fp = fopen($filename, 'r');

      $chunkLength = 0;
      while (count($tokens) < $n && $offset > 0) {
         $lastOffset = $offset;
         $offset -= $chunksize;
         if ($offset < 0) $offset = 0;             // can't seek before first byte

         $chunkLength += ($lastOffset - $offset);  // how much to read

         fseek($fp, $offset);
         $data = fread($fp, $chunkLength);         // read the next (previous) chunk

         if (($pos = strpos($data, $delimiter)) !== false) {
             $chunkLength = 0;                     // reset chunk size to read next time
             $offset += $pos;

             $data = explode($delimiter, substr($data, $pos + 1));
             array_unshift($data, & $tokens);      // make $tokens the $data array's first element 

             // with the last line, this is equivalent to 
             // array_push($tokens, $data[1], $data[2], $data[3], ....)
             call_user_func_array('array_push',  $data);
         }
      }
      fclose($fp);

   }

   fclose($fp);

   return array_slice($tokens, -$n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $file = "File contents"; //File get contents or anything else here.

    $array = explode(",", $file);

$array = array_slice($array, -10, 10); //Starting from Last 10th element, get Ten elements.
$string = implode(", ", $array);
echo $array;
```

Edit:

Changed the implementation to remove the loop and the count etc.

Comment: breaks if input has < 11 words.

Comment: You don't check whether the array has fewer entries.
See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = file_get_contents($file);               //get contents of file
$words = explode(',', $text);                   //split into array

if (($length = count($words) < 10) {
    $lastWords = $words;                        //shorter than 10 so return all
} else {
    for ($i = $length-11, $i < $length; $i++ {  //loop through last 10 words
        $lastWords[] = $words[$i];              //add to array
    }
}

$str = implode(',', $lastWords);                //change array back into a string
echo $str;
```